# How to conditionally define a lambda?

Tags: c++

The following function will randomly "sprinkle salt" on a loaded image. For the sake of boosting performance, the conditional statement

```
uint j = rows == 1 ? 0 : randomRow(generator);
```

should not be inside the loop.

Instead, I want to define a lambda `getJ` before the loop as

```
auto getJ = rows == 1 ? []() {return 0; } : []() {return randomRow(generator); };
```

However, my code with this lambda does not compile with the following red squiggled text:

[image]

## Question

How to conditionally define such a lambda?

```
void salt_(Mat mat, unsigned long long n)
{
    const uchar channels = mat.channels();
    uint cols = mat.cols;
    uint rows = mat.rows;

    if (mat.isContinuous())
    {
        cols *= rows;
        rows = 1;
    }

    default_random_engine generator;
    uniform_int_distribution<uint> randomRow(0, rows - 1);
    uniform_int_distribution<uint> randomCol(0, cols - 1);



    // auto getJ = rows == 1 ? []() {return 0; } : []() {return randomRow(generator); };


    uchar * const data = mat.data;

    for (unsigned long long counter = 0; counter < n; counter++)
    {
        uint i = randomCol(generator);
        uint j = rows == 1 ? 0 : randomRow(generator);
        //uint j = getJ();

        uint index = channels * (cols * j + i);
        for (uchar k = 0; k < channels; k++)
            data[index + k] = 255;
    }
}
```

Comment: "my code with this lambda does not compile" - What is the error you get?

Comment: You are trying to reference local variable `generator` without capturing it. If second lambda was capture-free it would compile.

Comment: Seems like a premature optimisation. Surely function call overhead would be greater than ternary overhead?

Comment: Is a conditional *really* a performance issue here? Have you profiled the code?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Yes. I always do benchmark.

Comment: @Artyer Done well, the call to the lambda can be inlined.

Comment: Benchmark is always right, but this is certainly not what I would expect. What is your platform? My experience is function call will not be faster for most desktop CPUs than a condition. You could create a template from your loop and pass `getJ` as a functor to it - that way there would be no overhead for it.

Comment: @Suma The great thing about lambdas is that the compiler knows exactly what it does so it is much easier to inline.  In this case there most likely wont be a function call and the `operator()` will be inlined into the code.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809985/are-functors-actually-faster-than-pointers-to-functions

Comment: @NathanOliver This assumes you pass your lambda into a function template. I doubt you can get this benefit when passing it as a std::function or a function pointer parameter into an ordinary function.

Comment: @Suma Correct.  But that is how you should be passing them.  Using a function pointer doesn't let you have state and `std::function` is expensive and is really only needed if you need to store the function for later like as a class member.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to manually [unswitch the loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unswitching). Why didn't your compiler do that automatically?

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for the useful information!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> my code with this lambda does not compile with the following red squiggled text

You cannot use `randomRow` inside the body of the lambda expression without *capturing* it beforehand, as the generated closure object needs to have access to it.

Even if you were to use `[&randomRow]`, the code would still fail to compile as every lambda expression produces a closure of **unique** type, even if the lambda expressions are exactly the same.

You can turn the problem on its head to avoid any overhead and achieve what you want - create a function that *takes* the lambda you want to invoke:

```
template <typename F>
void saltImpl(F&& getJ, /* ... */)
{
    uchar * const data = mat.data;

    for (unsigned long long counter = 0; counter < n; counter++)
    {
        uint i = randomCol(generator);
        uint j = rows == 1 ? 0 : randomRow(generator);
        //uint j = getJ();

        uint index = channels * (cols * j + i);
        for (uchar k = 0; k < channels; k++)
            data[index + k] = 255;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
void salt_(Mat mat, unsigned long long n)
{
    const uchar channels = mat.channels();
    uint cols = mat.cols;
    uint rows = mat.rows;

    if (mat.isContinuous())
    {
        cols *= rows;
        rows = 1;
    }

    default_random_engine generator;
    uniform_int_distribution<uint> randomRow(0, rows - 1);
    uniform_int_distribution<uint> randomCol(0, cols - 1);

    if (rows == 1)
    {
        saltImpl([]{ return 0; }, /* ... */);
    }
    else
    {
        saltImpl([&]{ return randomRow(generator); }, /* ... */)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not write a lambda that takes a lambda instead?

Answer (score 3):

Why this fails is because the lambdas are of a different type. That's natural, their `operator()` have different definitions. Which means you want your following code to work with two different types. And the C++ way of making code work with different types is using templates.

Convert the code using `getJ` to a function template (it can be local to your implementation file), like this:

```
template <class G>
void salt_impl_(Mat mat, unsigned long long n, default_random_engine &generator, G getJ)
{
    const uchar channels = mat.channels();
    uint cols = mat.cols;
    uint rows = mat.rows;

    if (mat.isContinuous())
    {
        cols *= rows;
        rows = 1;
    }

    uchar * const data = mat.data;

    uniform_int_distribution<uint> randomCol(0, cols - 1);

    for (unsigned long long counter = 0; counter < n; counter++)
    {
        uint i = randomCol(generator);
        uint j = getJ();

        uint index = channels * (cols * j + i);
        for (uchar k = 0; k < channels; k++)
            data[index + k] = 255;
    }
}


void salt_(Mat mat, unsigned long long n)
{
    const uchar channels = mat.channels();
    uint cols = mat.cols;
    uint rows = mat.rows;

    if (mat.isContinuous())
    {
        cols *= rows;
        rows = 1;
    }

    default_random_engine generator;
    uniform_int_distribution<uint> randomRow(0, rows - 1);

    if (rows == 1)
      salt_impl_(mat, n, generator, []() {return 0; });
    else
      salt_impl_(mat, n, generator, [&]() {return randomRow(generator); });
}
```

Feel free to reduce the initial-part duplication between the function and the template by passing more parameters, making them members of a class, or something similar.

Also note that the non-trivial lambda must capture the variables which it accesses (`randomRow` and `generator`). I did this using the universal by-reference capture `[&]` in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite the same thing, but you can set a `std::function` object to different lambdas based on a condition:

```
#include <functional>
...
std::function<int()> getJ;
if (rows == 1)
    getJ = [](){return 0;};
else
    getJ = [&](){return randomRow(generator);};
```